# Magento Admin Order Details page shows error

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

It displays an error "There has been an error processing your request. Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons" when i view the details of a particular order under Sales > Orders.

This issue occurs only for the recent orders.

I can view details of older orders.

FOLLOWING IS THE ERROR LOG I GOT
There has been an error processing your request
Image file was not found.

```
Trace:
#0 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php(163): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image->setBaseFile('')
#1 /home1/***/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml(50): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image->init(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 'small_image')
#2 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home1/***...')
#3 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#4 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#7 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Items/Abstract.php(177): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#8 /home1/***/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items.phtml(60): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Items_Abstract->getItemHtml(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item))
#9 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home1/***...')
#10 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#11 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#12 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#13 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('order_items', true)
#16 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Tab/Info.php(86): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('order_items')
#17 /home1/***/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml(92): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_Info->getItemsHtml()
#18 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home1/***...')
#19 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#20 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#21 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#22 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#23 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Tabs.php(303): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#24 /home1/***/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/tabs.phtml(38): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs->getTabContent(Object(Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_Info))
#25 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home1/***...')
#26 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#27 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#28 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#29 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#30 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#31 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#32 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#33 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#34 /home1/***/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(58): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#35 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home1/***...')
#36 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#37 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#38 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#39 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#40 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#41 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#42 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(128): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#43 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->viewAction()
#44 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#45 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#46 /home1/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#47 /home1/***/public_html/app/Mage.php(686): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#48 /home1/***/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('default', 'store')
#49 {main}
```

Comment: Raj,goto errors/ folder at magent dir here you have find the local.xml.sample,Just rename it  local.xml ad check the error

Comment: I enabled it. It now shows "Image file was not found."

Comment: please put screen shot

Comment: Your core is modified. There is no occurence of `init` in the template file `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml` in the default install. If you modified this or someone else did it, it was done wrong.

Comment: Oh. ok. I will check it @maurius.

Answer (score 1):

You issue with product image or product is not exiting in magento catalog

on items.phtml you call product image.it may this product is not this in magento.it delete but it details is   in sales.

before before call the  image you needcheck product is exit not

```
$prod=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
```

call image when product exit in magento

```
if($prod->getId()){
//  put your image code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable error printing by renaming `local.xml`.sample file to `local.xml` in errors directory and uncomment `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in `index.php` in root.

Comment: I enabled it. It now shows "Image file was not found."

Comment: have you done any customization to core files?

Comment: No. I haven't done.

Comment: I am able to view the details till Feb 12 Orders. After that I couldnt able to view it.

Comment: try to re-upload media directory if you have a backup

Comment: Ok. Let me try it out.

Comment: all images exists already.

Comment: I have pasted in my question

Comment: Refresh the cache and try again

Comment: I cleared it. But still it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You should see a long number on the screen along with the error message.
Look in the var/report folder for a file with the same name as the long number. That one contains the error message and stacktrace.
But without knowing what the file contains I will shoot in the dark and say that you had a certain payment method enabled at one point, the order was placed using that payment method and then you removed it.
This is (from my point of view) a drawback of Magento. You cannot remove payment methods that have been used for past orders. You can just disable them.

In case I'm wrong, just paste the contents of the error file in your question and I will try to come up with something better.

Comment: I enabled it. It now shows "Image file was not found."